# ecto query missing from clause from entry table

Tags: elixir, ecto

Does anyone know why I am getting this error
`** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 12345 (undefined_table) missing FROM-clause entry for table "ph"`

```
    my_query =
      from(p in M,
        join: rt in R,
        on: rt.id == p.id,
        where: rt.name == "Some String" and p.name == "Another String",
        select: %{
          id: p.id,
          name: p.name,
          number: p.number
        }
      )

    another_query =
      from(e in E,
        ...
        left_join: ph in subquery(my_query),
        on: fragment("ph.id::text = e.id::text"),
```

I am trying to use `my_query` as a subquery in a larger query but I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you rewrite the `on` part in `another_query`:

```
on: fragment("?::text", ph.id) == fragment("?::text", e.id)
```

(disclaimer: not tested)